# Sound proofing of studio equipment

Tags: isolation, studio-design

I want to build an acoustically isolated rack for some studio equipment, and would like advice on its design. I need to reduce the volume of the fans of the amplifiers. Their power dissipation are low, so I will likely just need a single quiet pc fan for cooling the rack; I have found fans that are significantly quieter than those of the amplifiers, so I could simply mount one on the rack. However I don't know:

**what the rack should be constructed of for appropriate attenuation, or what linings to use, and any other measures such as mounts for the rack (which will be floor-standing on concrete), and mounting the amps to the rack. **

(The amps will not need to be accessed during normal use once installed). Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it to be really quiet and wont be accessing the amps after they are installed, your best bet might be to just put them in a seperate room so that it will be acoustically isolated completely. If they are in the same room, you might want a case with a door to reduce the sound the amps produce.

Answer (score 1):

Don't put equipment that makes noise in the room that you are sampling audio from.  There shouldn't be anything at all in the room.  Preferably even the ventilation should be independent so you can shut it down during recording.  (I've often seen where they just put an A/C unit in a window and block off all the other vents.)  That's always going to get you the best sound isolation you can hope for.  Too many other problems since deadening sound also means killing airflow.